# C# SqlDataReader.GetInt64 System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I know the usual answers for this and they don't seem to apply.

We have a process that goes through data from numerous vendors and gets it into one consistent stream.  We added a vendor recently that required a change to our primary key to a bigint.

Some of the string massaging was just easier to do in C#, so I changed the C# code from

```
primaryKey = reader.GetInt32(0);
```

to

```
primaryKey = reader.GetInt64(0);
```

figuring that the older vendors in the system would just cast cleanly up to Int64.

I got everybody up and running and I noticed that *some* but not all of one of the older vendor's records (the int32 primary key) were getting processed.  Looking in the log files, I was seeing **InvalidCastException** on the reader.GetInt64() call processing some batches.

I know the usual response is "Oh, you're probably getting nulls", but

- it is a primary key.  It can't be null
- The code's been running with the reader.GetInt32(0) call for over a decade
- all the numbers in all the batches (successful and unsuccessful) are in the 181 million range

I changed the code to throw an ArgumentNullException if IsDBNull() came back true, but that never tripped.

The stack trace has

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int64()
```

but without source or line number it's hard to get farther.

I put

```
CAST(keyID as bigint) keyID
```

in the stored procedure returning the batches, and the issue has gone away.

Still curious though.  Why would reader.GetInt64() throw an InvalidCastException sporadically when given an Int32 in the query result?

Comment: I'm not going to speculate on reasons, but yes: database types can do weird things (source: I wrote Dapper, I've dealt with *a lot* of data reader code). Tools like Dapper will do the right thing for you, checking the types in advance. Maybe just use one of them?

Comment: @user1664043: any specific value that fails the casting?

Comment: The obvious thing to do would be to check the column type `reader.GetFieldType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would reader.GetInt64() throw an InvalidCastException sporadically when given an Int32 in the query result?

`reader.GetInt64()` should throw an InvalidCastException not just "sporadically" but *every single time*. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint64):

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a 64-bit signed integer.

In other words, if the column value is an Int32, then GetInt64 will throw InvalidCastException. It won't convert the Int32 to an Int64 for you. The same goes for all the other SqlDataReader.Get... methods.

Probably the best fix is to adjust the SQL query to always return Int64 values, as you've done. Alternatively, to handle both Int32 and Int64 values, you could read the column value as an `object` and then perform a conversion using `Convert.ToInt64(reader[0])`.